Torah Traits and Omer
I heard that the 48 days of the Omer line up with the 48 traits of acquiring Torah in Pirkei Avot, and the 49th day corresponds to doing chazara on all of them. Does anyone have a list of each trait and which matching Omer date is corresponds to?

See: https://aish.com/52829142/
